# sugarCRM migrating Leads module

Tags: sugarcrm, data-migration, database-migration

I am trying to move sugarCRM data (Leads, Opportunities and Applicants, these are modules in sugarCRM) - I have the .csv files. No SQL.its hosted by this company and they won't give me the sql.
the issue is that leads for example has 212 columns(fields)
the regular sugarCRM has far less fields. 
I am trying to figure out what is the best way to import all the data without having to use the Studio to create each field individually.
Opportunities module has 110 fields also on the hosted version - and the regular sugarCRM only has about 27.
so my question is how do I  create all the fields so I can import them
I already created a file that gets the  column names, and I did import  all the data into a table called Leads1. when I rename it to leads and check ... the data doesnt show on the page.
any ideas? (please dont answer and say : ask the company to send you the sql, because they will not send it they know I want to move out of their hosted environment I already spent an hour on the phone and they wouldn't)

any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 3):

With or without the SQL you'll need to recreate the fields in Studio as you need the views to also include the fields. It's tedious, but the only real viable option in this case. It is important that the fields are named exactly the same when doing this so that the import works correctly.

If you can hack some code, another option is to create a module that will export the SQL for the whole database for you from within SugarCRM and also the whole file structure as a zip so that you don't have to recreate anything.

BTW - make sure that the SugarCRM instance you are moving to is the exact same version. Once you do the import then you can upgrade to your desired version. This guarantees that the DB structure will be the same then (given that the custom fields get created appropriately).

Good luck!

Comment: I can write the code but I dont have permission on the hosted version even the admin area is not accessible. Thanks for all your help so obviously it comes down to adding the fields individually ahhh.

Comment: Seeing that you are on OD, you could also contact Sugar support to help you with these needs.